# Search preceding and following characters of re

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the characters immediately before and after a regex match in a given string. This is the code.

```
>>>import re
>>>s='dafddadffdbdasbffsbbfdbabbfsdfadsfdfddf' #completely garbage test string
>>>re.findall('.{0,5}(abb).{0,5}',s)
['abb']
```

The test string has an occurence of 'abb' here `...fdbabbfsd...` I am under the impression that the special character `.` matches *any* character other than `\n` and the `{m,n} Causes the resulting RE to match from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as many repetitions as possible` as stated [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

So I expect my re to return `['bbfdbabbfsdfa']` and not just `['abb']`. What am I missing?

Comment: You have a capturing group; `.findall()` returns just the groups.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What are my alternatives?

Comment: Use this `re.findall('(.{0,5}abb.{0,5})',s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the capturing group. Just move the parentheses:

```
re.findall('(.{0,5}abb.{0,5})',s)
```

`findall` only matches groups, so everything you want to match needs to be in the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

According to [`re.findall` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups**; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group.

So by surrounding whole pattern as a group or removing group will give you what you want.

```
>>> re.findall('(.{0,5}abb.{0,5})',s)  # Entire pattern as a group
['bbfdbabbfsdfa']
>>> re.findall('.{0,5}abb.{0,5}',s)    # No capturing group
['bbfdbabbfsdfa']
```